# error in c# :One Or More Error Messages Occurred During Processing Of Command

Tags: c#, oracle

this is my code:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=data;Password=ss8_pakhsh;User ID=SHIFTS_N";
            con.Open();
int MAXID = 1175;
 MAXID++;
string sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO GROUPS(GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME,DEPT_ID) " +
                              "VALUES(" + MAXID + ",'"
                              + textBox1.Text +
                             "', SELECT DEPT_ID FROM PERSONNEL_TEMP.DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME="+comboBox1.Text;
 OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlcommand, con);
            oda.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
```

while i running it ,gets this error :

> One or more errors occurred during processing of command.

i think my query has problem because when i enter it on TOAD editor(for oracle) gets me this error:

> ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Incorrect quotes may lead you error..check the quotes string .and most important SQL injection!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing quotes and paranthesis in your query.

[SQL Injection Alert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx)

To avoid this you should use Parameterized queries as like follows

```
string sqlcommand ="INSERT INTO GROUPS(GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME,DEPT_ID)  
                           VALUES(?,?,SELECT DEPT_ID FROM PERSONNEL_TEMP.DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME=?)";
OleDbConnection oledbConnection = new OleDbConnection(con);
OleDbCommand oledbCommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlcommand , oledbConnection);
oledbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtquotationno.Text);
oledbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", cmbjobcode.Text);
oledbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", comboBox1.Text);
OleDbDataAdapter oda  = new OleDbDataAdapter(oledbCommand);
DataTable dt= new DataTable();
oda.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: I DO IT BUT STILL GETS ME ERROR

Comment: THE ERROR Occurred ON  oda.Fill(dt);

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `select` query in braces as you are selecting this from another table so this shoould be in `()`. Also `Department_Name` looks of `type varchar`so its value should be in `single quotes`. Change your query like this.

```
string sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO GROUPS(GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME,DEPT_ID) " +
                              "VALUES(" + MAXID + ",'"
                              + textBox1.Text +
                             "',(SELECT DEPT_ID FROM PERSONNEL_TEMP.DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME='"+comboBox1.Text+"'"));
```

Also use `parameterized` query to prevent `sql injection`.